# two phase sample weights

Tags: r, sampling, survey

I am using survey package to analyze data from a two-phase survey. The first phase included ~5000 cases, and the second ~2700. Weights were calculated beforehand to adjust for several variables (ethnicity, sex, etc.) AND(as far as I understand) for the decrease in sample size when performing phase 2.

I'm interested in proportions of binary variables, e.g. suicides in sick vs. healthy individuals.

An example of a simple output I receive **in the overall sample**:

```
table (df$schiz,df$suicide)
    0       1
 0 4857     8
 1 24       0
```

An example of a simple output I receive **in the second phase sample only**:

```
table (df2$schiz,df2$suicide)
    0       1
 0 2685     5
 1 24       0
```

And **within the phase two sample** with the weights included:

```
dfw<-svydesign(ids=~1,data=df2, weights=df2$weights) 
svytable (~schiz+suicide, design=dfW)


      suicide     
schiz    0          1
0        2701.51    2.67
1        18.93      0.00
```

My question is: Shouldn't the weights correct for the decrease in N when moving from phase 1 to phase 2? i.e. shouldn't the total N of the second table after correction be ~5000 cases, and not ~2700 as it is now?